# ALSA-OSS installed , no dev/dsp found

Tags: fedora, alsa, voice-command

I'm using Fedora 16 - sound works fine.

I've tried to execute Pocketsphinx for some tests with voice recognition, but it depends on OSS to work. It crashes with the message:

```
ad_oss.c(103): Failed to open audio device(/dev/dsp): No such file or directory
```

I have ALSA-OSS installed but im getting the same error.

Comment: What's the output of `lsmod | grep snd_seq_oss`? If there's no output, try doing `modprobe snd_seq_oss`.

Comment: I tried with lsmod | grep snd_seq_oss but there's no output.
And i tried with modprobe snd_seq_oss and there's no output too. What is happening?

Comment: Please add any additional information to your question by editing it, instead of posting new "answers". This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

For `/dev/dsp` to work, the actual sound driver must be loaded (check index 0 in `/proc/asound/cards`), and the `snd-pcm-oss` module must be loaded.